# callback method while loop javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, callback

I want to use a callback function in a `while` loop like this:

```
do {
    Methodwithcallback(..function () {
        //do something  
    });
}
while ();
```

`function()` will not be called, but it is working without a `loop`.

The Method take some time to execute and i want to repeat the `loop` after the Method is finished.

Why is the Method being ignored in the `loop`? I'm using `Node.js`

Comment: Is `Methodwithcallback` asynchronous ?

Comment: the function is executed asynchronous.

Comment: what is the condition of the while loop? Can you confirm that the method was ignored (e.g logging inside the callback)

Comment: It is an infinite loop to check if a file exists. If it does the file should be uploaded and the loop repeats with a counter+1. I can confirm that the method is ignored.

Comment: Either you wait for the asynchronous method to finish (this eliminates the benefit of asynchronism), or you make your outer scope asynchronous too

Answer (score 1):

You can't use loops with asynchronous functions like that - the loop wants to execute "now", and the callback executes "later"..

Try with something like this:

```
function callback() {
    // do whatever else is needed
    methodWithCallback(callback); // start the next one
}

methodWithCallback(callback); // start the first one
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive callback handler that knows when to stop based on a base case, in the below code it executes once for each item in `arr`. Also you can use [`async.series()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) which is a pre-made library to handle this.

```
const arr = [...items]
let count = 0

const blockingHandler = () => {
    // Keep track of times invoked
    count++

    // Do something

    // If there is another item to execute, then do it
    if (count < arr.length) {
        MethodwithCallback(blockingHandler))
    }
}

MethodwithCallback(blockingHandler)
```

If you want to use Promises, [`bluebird`](https://bluebirdjs.com) has [`mapSeries()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) which will serially iterate over a collection with the given async function.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const arr = [...items]

Promise.mapSeries(arr, i => {
    MethodwithCallback(() => {
        /* 
         * If there was some error handling you could check for an error
         * if there is one, then return a rejected Promise
         * if (err) {
         *   return Promise.reject(err)
         * }
         */

        // do something

        return Promise.resolve()
    })
})
    .then(() => console.log('All Promises Complete'))
    .catch(err => console.log('An error occurred', err))
```

If `MethodwithCallback()` can be [promisified](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html), then we can shorten this code a little. Promisification is now built into Node as well via [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const asyncMethod = Promise.promisify(MethodwithCallback)
const arr = [...items]

Promise.mapSeries(arr, i => {
    return asyncMethod()
        .then(() => {
            // do something specific for this item
        })
})
  .then(() => {
    // do something when all items done
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // An error occurred during mapSeries
    console.log('An error occurred', err)
  })
```